# Using sklearn and pandas in AWS Lambda Layer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, aws-lambda

I was able to successfully follow this tutorial [here](https://onema.io/blog/scikit-learn-layer-for-aws-lambda/) to zip a `scikit-learn` package and create a layer. Now I have two layers loaded, one for `scikit-learn` and one for `numpy` and `scipy` that AWS already has. You can see that below

[image]

When I try to run my lambda now, I get an error that states that

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'"
```

Thus I tried to do the same process with zipping up a pandas file together but when I try to load it, I exceed that 50mb maximum. Is there anyway of loading in pandas and sklearn together so that I do not go above this maximum limit?

Comment: Upload your zip first to s3, and then link the S3 zip.

Comment: @Marcin How would that help? You still have to create the layer either from a zip file or an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [docker container as Lambda images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). This will allow you to use way bigger libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The 50 MB limit is for upload only. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html):

> 50 MB (zipped, for **direct upload**)

If you want to have greater layers, you have to upload them to S3 first. Then the 50 MB limit does not apply and you are constrained by:

> 250 MB (unzipped, including layers)

Comment: Okay, I uploaded the zip files to s3, but to add a layer you still have to create them in Lambda and add them. So I am not sure how that will help.

Comment: @justanewb Your issue is that you exceed 50 MB limit from what I understand. Now it will not apply.

Comment: I apologize, I must not understand. Could you explain in steps through AWS how I achieve what you are saying. So far I have all my zipped python modules in a S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following repo which includes a process for creating lambda layers. It includes configuration for sklearn (with pandas, numpy and scipy).

You clone it and use a CLI with details like python version and architecture.

https://github.com/imperva/aws-lambda-layer

Note: Docker must be installed on the machine you run the process (you can use docker desktop) since it uses docker build